# Can Login Items be added via the command line in High Sierra?

Tags: terminal, login-items

Can Login Items be added via a command in terminal?

I would like to add a few essential utilities like [ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt) and [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com) to my Login Items via a script when I'm configuring a new Mac. In versions of macOS previous to High Sierra these items were stored in a plist in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist` but since High Sierra has been released it seems they've been [migrated to be loaded via a new mechanism](https://discussions.apple.com/message/32423169).

I am interested in ways to set Login Items from a terminal primarily for High Sierra but interested from an academic perspective to know how it could be done in prior releases of macOS.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**macOS Catalina Update:** While the information in this answer holds true as stated and tested in the versions of **OS X**/**macOS** listed below, it does not work in **macOS Catalina 10.15**.

---

I tested the following under **macOS 10.14.6**, **macOS 10.13.1** and **OS X 10.8.6**.

In **Terminal**, using the following *syntax*:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to make login item at end with properties {path:"/path/to/itemname", hidden:false}'
```

- <sub>Note: If there are *spaces* in a *path filename*, do not escape the *spaces* with a *backslash* (`\`) when it is in *quotes*.</sub>

Tested with an application named **EventScripts**:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to make login item at end with properties {path:"/Applications/EventScripts.app", hidden:false}'
```

It returned:

```
login item UNKNOWN
```

Which is apparently the normal output with this command and was verified by preforming the same action in **Script Editor**.

Then looking in **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups** > **$USER** > **Login Items**, **EventScripts** was added.

---

**Notes:**

In **OS X 10.8.6** it updated the following file:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist
```

In **macOS 10.13.1**<sup>[1]</sup> it updated the following file:

```
~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.backgroundtaskmanagementagent/backgrounditems.btm
```

Which, by the way, is also a **plist** file, but with a **btm** extension.

You can also delete a **Login Item** from **Terminal** using the following *syntax*:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to delete login item "name"'
```

Where `"name"` in the *command* is as show in the *output* of the following *command*:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get the name of every login item'
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Update: The `backgrounditems.btm` file is still the target file since **macOS 10.13.1** and later.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed and I've integrated it into my bootstrapping scripts.

Comment: did you find a way for Catalina?

Comment: @Ciprian Tomoiagă, As of Nov 26, 19, when I added the note "**macOS Catalina Update:** While the information in this answer holds true as stated and tested in the versions of **OS X/macOS** listed below, it does not work in **macOS Catalina 10.15**."  I have not tested since then and the last version I tested it on was 10.15.1.

Comment: Thank you ! I thought maybe you had found a workaround :D

Comment: I was able to use this command on Big Sur and it worked fine.

Comment: Also fine in Monterey.

Answer (score 0):

On Catalina & beyond the path to Applications has changed, so, adding Login Items might require using something like "/System/Applications/Awesome App.app"