# Add login item from command line

Tags: terminal

Found the following [Can Login Items be added via the command line in High Sierra?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310495/can-login-items-be-added-via-the-command-line-in-high-sierra#)

which I'm trying to adapt to add a login item in 10.14.6

I realize that it's a somewhat old thread by now, but I've been trying with the following, in 10.14.6, adapted from the solved in thread linked above:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to make login item at end with properties {path:"/Applications/cDock.app/Contents/Resources/cDock\ Helper.app", hidden:false}'
```

But keep getting the following error:

syntax error: Expected “"” but found unknown token. (-2741)

Can someone perhaps suggest how to rewrite this to avoid the error?

Comment: Knew that somewhere in the back of my head, but had forgotten all about it. That did the job, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the *backslash* (`\`) from: `cDock\ Helper.app`

You do not need to escape *spaces* in a *path filename* when it is in *quotes*.

Only escape *spaces* in a *path filename* when it is **not** in *quotes*.

Never do both, (in this use case).